# How to use OR operator inside IF in php?

Tags: php

I've been trying to perform this code in PHP:

```
if(!afunction() || !anotherfunction()) {code}
```

the functions are predefined and return true or false, but only the first condition works, not the second.

Comment: If `afunction()` is false then `anotherfunction()` will never execute.  Maybe you want `&&` ?

Comment: More specifically, if `!afunction()` evaluates to `true` then the `another_function()` is not ran, as the requirements of the conditional have already been met, so it has moved on from checking conditions. The reason for this being that `and` as well as `or` operators (and their symbolic equivalents) are both implemented as [short circuit evaluations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (there's a demonstration of this).

Comment: OR in this case means EITHER one, so if the first is false then it doesn't need to check the second.  AND means BOTH, so both need to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to a common optimization that most languages make.

- In the expression `A || B` if `A` evaluates to `true` there's no reason to evaluate `B` at all because no matter what result `B` returns the expression can never be anything but `true`.
- In the expression `A && B` if `A` evaluates to `false` there's no reason to evaluate `B` at all because no matter what result `B` returns the expression can never be anything but `false`.

If you want both functions to always run regardless then you'll need to do that outside of the context of the logical expression, eg:

```
$a_result = a();
$b_result = b();

if( ! $a_result || ! $b_result ) {
  // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1 = true;
$var2 = true;
if($var1 == true || $var2 == true) {
  echo "Var1 or Var2 hold true value";
} // '||' is the OR operator
```

Answer (score -2):

Use "or"
Ie.
If($x==1 or $y==2)...

Comment: Using `or` in place of `||` will not change this. These only vary in precedence. There is more information about this [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)